# Convert string obtained by str() function back to list

Tags: python, string, list

I am working with database that does not support json documents in relational tables.
I am storing small lists like `a=[1,2,3]` as string `b=str(a)`.
As a result, I have `b='[1, 2, 3]'`. After fetching this string from database, I want to convert it back to list.

Is there a generic python function that does the correct conversion? Calling `c=list(b)` results in `c=['[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ']']`.

My list entries can be integer numbers (including negative), floats (with up to 5 digits after coma), and short strings.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Comment: You should use `json.dumps` and `json.loads` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. It seems like this is the best way in my case